# How can I create an IPhone app that accesses magnetometer data and transmits it to my desktop

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I want to use an app for the iphone that accesses the magnetometer data and transmits it over bluetooth to my desktop for real-time use.

Will I be able to do this using TechBasic?
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/techbasic/id470781862?mt=8

Answer (score 2):

A CMMotionManager object is the gateway to the motion services provided by iOS. These services provide an app with accelerometer data, rotation-rate data, magnetometer data, and other device-motion data such as attitude.

Try to use CMMotionManager Class in iOS to read magnetometer data. Check This [LINK-CMMotionManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

and Use CoreBluetooh Framework to transmit this data. Here is [AppleCode Sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/BTLE_Transfer/Introduction/Intro.html)

Hope this will helps u.

Comment: Cool, I was looking for this some time ago before BTLE / CoreBluetooth existed. I make a mind note that it is now possible :)

Comment: Dude come on, 3 upvotes just for a link to and a quote from the docs? These sort of answers really defeat the purpose of stackoverflow

Comment: @doctordoder: i think u dont know the purpose of stackoverflow. the purpose of stackoverflow is to give proper direction to resolve the problem with urself, not to give the exact solution of the ans. some of the person are here wants that someone else do their work and they never try anything.